# How to dynamically return fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a webapi project in C # with EF, when I get a GET request in it comes which fields the EF should return to the client.

Currently the fields are fixed:

http://localhost/clients

```
  function dynaminc Get(){
return (from object in db where field1 == "1" select new {field1,field2, field3}).ToList();
  }
```

but I would like something similar:

http://localhost/clients?fields=field1,field2,field3

```
   function dynaminc Get(string fields){
    return (from object in db where field1 == "1" select new {fields}).ToList();
   }
```

Comment: It's not super hard to create an Expression Tree that'd do it for you, But it's not exactly easy and it has a bit of learning curve - Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Answer (score 0):

You can either create and object and pass it using post or you can pass these variables one by one in the request and read them as FromUri in the controller action . If you need any sample code I can provide that .